# How can I recover Form 8582 needed for this year tax?

Tags: united-states, taxes, florida

How could I recover a copy of my Form 8582 from last year (needed for this year) for the state of Florida?

My accountant that did my taxes is not being helpful and does not reply to my messages. He may have it but I will need to find another way to get it.

Comment: Contact whoever issued that form in the first place and ask for a duplicate. They should be able to send you one.

Comment: @keshlam this form is a part of the tax return package, no-one sends it to you

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [form 4506](https://www.irs.gov/uac/About-Form-4506) to request a copy of your tax return. You can also just [ask for transcript](https://www.irs.gov/Individuals/Get-Transcript), that may be faster but may not be as easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

Do you not have a copy of your past tax returns?  Since 2007 just about every accountant I have used has emailed me a copy of my return.  If you don't, you need to work on getting them and keeping them.  Put them in a cloud account like OneDrive (which is free) or DropBox.  Recouping your passive losses is extremely important and you have to be able to justify them as well.

Perhaps it is time to stop calling and emailing your accountant and make a drive to his office......and them find a new one.  I personally use US Tax Shield.